Как сделать сохранение внесенных данных в файл.ini, QSettings?
Есть приложение, в котором изредка понадобиться изменять некоторые параметры, 
которые перезаписываются в переменной (propCity, normCity и т.д.).
Но после закрытия приложения естественно все ново внесенные параметры сбрасываются.
Подскажите как сделать, чтобы новые параметры сохранялись в .ini файл и в будущем, при внесении других параметров, они перезаписывались в этом же файле?
Пытался поковыряться с QSettings, но так его до конца и не понял.

app.py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from PySide6.QtCore import QSettings
from design import Ui_root

sys.argv += ['-platform', 'windows:darkmode=1']


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_root):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # setting
        self.btnSet.clicked.connect(self.saveProperty)
        self.btnSet.setShortcut(QApplication.translate("root", u"Ctrl+S", None))

        # property
        self.propCity = None
        self.propHighway = None
        self.normCity = None
        self.normHighway = None
        self.propCityWinter = None
        self.normCityWinter = None
        self.propHighwayWinter = None
        self.normHighwayWinter = None

        # function
        self.btnSummer.clicked.connect(self.funcSummer)
        self.btnWinter.clicked.connect(self.funcWinter)

        # menubar
        self.btnAbout.clicked.connect(self.funcAbout)
        self.btnHelp.clicked.connect(self.funcHelp)
        self.btnGear.setCheckable(True)
        self.btnGear.clicked.connect(self.funcGear)

        # summer
        self.applyPropCitySummer.clicked.connect(self.newPropCitySummer)
        self.applyNormCitySummer.clicked.connect(self.newNormCitySummer)
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.clicked.connect(self.newPropHighwaySummer)
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.clicked.connect(self.newNormHighwaySummer)

        #winter
        self.applyPropCityWinter.clicked.connect(self.newPropCityWinter)
        self.applyNormCityWinter.clicked.connect(self.newNormCityWinter)
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.clicked.connect(self.newPropHighwayWinter)
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.clicked.connect(self.newNormHighwayWinter)

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    def saveProperty(self):

        settings = QSettings("setting.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)

        settings.setValue("setting.ini", self.propCity)
        settings.setValue("setting.ini", self.propHighway)
        settings.setValue("setting.ini", self.normCity)
        settings.setValue("setting.ini", self.normHighway)
        settings.setValue("setting.ini", self.propCityWinter)
        settings.setValue("setting.ini", self.normCityWinter)
        settings.setValue("setting.ini", self.propHighwayWinter)
        settings.setValue("setting.ini", self.normHighwayWinter)

        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Настройки', f"Новые данные сохранены.")

        settings.sync()

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # summer
    def funcSummer(self):
        try:
            # Пропорции город лето
            if self.propCity:
                propCity = self.propCity
            else:
                propCity = 0.3

                # Нормы город лето
            if self.normCity:
                normCity = self.normCity
            else:
                normCity = 11.5

                # Пропорции трасса лето
            if self.propHighway:
                propHighway = self.propHighway
            else:
                propHighway = 0.7

                # Нормы трасса лето
            if self.normHighway:
                normHighway = self.normHighway
            else:
                normHighway = 8.5

            inSummer = float(self.inputSummer.text())
            roadCity = round(propCity * inSummer, 2)
            roadHighway = round(propHighway * inSummer, 2)
            resultCity = round(propCity * inSummer / 100 * normCity, 2)
            resultHighway = round(propHighway * inSummer / 100 * normHighway, 2)
            totalSummer = round((propCity * inSummer / 100 * normCity) + (propHighway * inSummer / 100 * normHighway),
                                2)
            self.outSummer.setText(
                f' Ваш расход составил {totalSummer} литров\n\n'
                f' Детальная информация \n'
                f' Пробег по городу {roadCity} км \n'
                f' Расход по городу {resultCity} литров\n'
                f' Пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км \n'
                f' Расход по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                f' Нормы расхода\n'
                f' Город {normCity} на 100 км\n'
                f' Трасса {normHighway} на 100 км\n\n'
                f' Пропорции\n'
                f' Коэф. по городу {propCity}\n'
                f' Коэф. по трассе {propHighway}'
            )
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                                  f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newPropCitySummer(self):
        try:
            self.propCity = float(self.inputPropCitySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()

        except Exception as e:
            self.propCity = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputPropCitySummer.text()}</b>")

    def newNormCitySummer(self):
        try:
            self.normCity = float(self.inputNormCitySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normCity = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputNormCitySummer.text()}</b>")

    def newPropHighwaySummer(self):
        try:
            self.propHighway = float(self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propHighway = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text()}</b>")

    def newNormHighwaySummer(self):
        try:
            self.normHighway = float(self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normHighway = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text()}</b>")

            # winter

    # winter

    def funcWinter(self):

        try:
            if self.propCityWinter:  # Пропорции город зима
                propCityWinter = self.propCityWinter
            else:
                propCityWinter = 0.3

            if self.normCityWinter:  # Нормы город зима
                normCityWinter = self.normCityWinter
            else:
                normCityWinter = 13.8

            if self.propHighwayWinter:  # Пропорции трасса зима
                propHighwayWinter = self.propHighwayWinter
            else:
                propHighwayWinter = 0.7

            if self.normHighwayWinter:  # Нормы трасса зима
                normHighwayWinter = self.normHighwayWinter
            else:
                normHighwayWinter = 10.2

            inWinter = float(self.inputWinter.text())
            roadCity = round(propCityWinter * inWinter, 2)
            roadHighway = round(propHighwayWinter * inWinter, 2)
            resultCity = round(propCityWinter * inWinter / 100 * normCityWinter, 2)
            resultHighway = round(propHighwayWinter * inWinter / 100 * normHighwayWinter, 2)
            totalWinter = round((propCityWinter * inWinter / 100 * normCityWinter) + (
                    propHighwayWinter * inWinter / 100 * normHighwayWinter), 2)
            self.outWinter.setText(
                f' Ваш расход составил {totalWinter} литров\n\n'
                f' Детальная информация \n'
                f' Пробег по городу {roadCity} км \n'
                f' Расход по городу {resultCity} литров\n'
                f' Пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км \n'
                f' Расход по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                f' Нормы расхода\n'
                f' Город {normCityWinter} на 100 км\n'
                f' Трасса {normHighwayWinter} на 100 км\n\n'
                f' Пропорции\n'
                f' Коэф. по городу {propCityWinter}\n'
                f' Коэф. по трассе {propHighwayWinter}'
            )

        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                                  f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newPropCityWinter(self):
        try:
            self.propCityWinter = float(self.inputPropCityWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propCityWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newNormCityWinter(self):
        try:
            self.normCityWinter = float(self.inputNormCityWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normCityWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newPropHighwayWinter(self):
        try:
            self.propHighwayWinter = float(self.inputPropHighwayWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propHighwayWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newNormHighwayWinter(self):
        try:
            self.normHighwayWinter = float(self.inputNormHighwayWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normHighwayWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    # bar
    def funcGear(self):
        if self.btnGear.isChecked():
            self.resize(560, 670)
        else:
            self.resize(560, 450)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

design.py
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
                            QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
                            QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
                           QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
                           QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
                           QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMainWindow,
                               QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QTabWidget, QWidget)
import files_rc


class Ui_root(object):
    def setupUi(self, root):
        if not root.objectName():
            root.setObjectName(u"root")

        root.resize(560, 450)
        root.setMinimumSize(QSize(560, 450))
        root.setMaximumSize(QSize(560, 670))
        root.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        root.setMouseTracking(False)
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(u":/icon/icon.ico", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        root.setWindowIcon(icon)
        root.setWindowOpacity(1.000000000000000)
        root.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        root.setStyleSheet(u"")
        root.setDocumentMode(False)
        root.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Rounded)

        self.grid_w = QWidget(root)
        self.grid_w.setObjectName(u"grid_w")
        self.grid_w.setStyleSheet(u"")

        self.inputSummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputSummer.setObjectName(u"inputSummer")
        self.inputSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 40, 241, 31))
        self.inputSummer.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.inputSummer.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputSummer.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.inputSummer.setMaxLength(32767)
        self.inputSummer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.inputSummer.setDragEnabled(False)

        self.outSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.outSummer.setObjectName(u"outSummer")
        self.outSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 130, 241, 281))
        self.outSummer.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 230);")
        self.outSummer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)

        self.btnSummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnSummer.setObjectName(u"btnSummer")
        self.btnSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 80, 241, 41))
        self.btnSummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnSummer.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.btnSummer.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)

        self.btnWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnWinter.setObjectName(u"btnWinter")
        self.btnWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 80, 241, 41))
        self.btnWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnWinter.setStyleSheet(u"")

        self.outWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.outWinter.setObjectName(u"outWinter")
        self.outWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 130, 241, 281))
        self.outWinter.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);")
        self.outWinter.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.outWinter.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)

        self.inputWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputWinter.setObjectName(u"inputWinter")
        self.inputWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 40, 241, 31))
        self.inputWinter.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputWinter.setMaxLength(10)

        self.label_s = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.label_s.setObjectName(u"label_s")
        self.label_s.setGeometry(QRect(20, 10, 241, 21))
        self.label_s.setStyleSheet(u"")

        self.lable_w = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.lable_w.setObjectName(u"lable_w")
        self.lable_w.setGeometry(QRect(300, 10, 241, 21))
        self.lable_w.setStyleSheet(u"")

        # about

        self.btnAbout = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnAbout.setObjectName(u"btnAbout")
        self.btnAbout.setGeometry(QRect(20, 417, 29, 28))
        self.btnAbout.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnAbout.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon1 = QIcon()
        icon1.addFile(u"res/button/btn_about.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btnAbout.setIcon(icon1)

        # help

        self.btnHelp = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnHelp.setObjectName(u"btnHelp")
        self.btnHelp.setGeometry(QRect(53, 417, 29, 28))
        self.btnHelp.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnHelp.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon2 = QIcon()
        icon2.addFile(u"res/button/btn_help.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btnHelp.setIcon(icon2)
        self.btnHelp.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btnHelp.setFlat(False)

        # setting

        self.btnSet = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnSet.setObjectName(u"btnSet")
        self.btnSet.setGeometry(QRect(476, 417, 30, 28))
        self.btnSet.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnSet.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon3 = QIcon()
        icon3.addFile(u"res/button/btn_setting.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btnSet.setIcon(icon3)

        # property

        self.btnGear = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnGear.setObjectName(u"btnGear")
        self.btnGear.setGeometry(QRect(510, 417, 30, 28))
        self.btnGear.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnGear.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon3 = QIcon()
        icon3.addFile(u"res/button/btn_config.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btnGear.setIcon(icon3)

        self.labelPropSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelPropSummer.setObjectName(u"labelPropSummer")
        self.labelPropSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 470, 71, 16))

        self.applyPropCitySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setObjectName(u"applyPropCitySummer")
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 490, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.labelNormSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelNormSummer.setObjectName(u"labelNormSummer")
        self.labelNormSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 570, 91, 16))

        self.applyNormHighwaySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"applyNormHighwaySummer")
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 630, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.applyPropHighwaySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"applyPropHighwaySummer")
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 530, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.applyNormCitySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setObjectName(u"applyNormCitySummer")
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 590, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.applyNormCityWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setObjectName(u"applyNormCityWinter")
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 590, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.applyNormHighwayWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"applyNormHighwayWinter")
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 630, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.applyPropCityWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setObjectName(u"applyPropCityWinter")
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 490, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.applyPropHighwayWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"applyPropHighwayWinter")
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 530, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.labelPropWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelPropWinter.setObjectName(u"labelPropWinter")
        self.labelPropWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 470, 71, 16))

        self.labelNormWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelNormWinter.setObjectName(u"labelNormWinter")
        self.labelNormWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 570, 91, 16))

        self.inputPropCitySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setObjectName(u"inputPropCitySummer")
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 491, 151, 31))

        self.inputPropHighwaySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"inputPropHighwaySummer")
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 530, 151, 31))

        self.inputPropCityWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setObjectName(u"inputPropCityWinter")
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 490, 151, 31))

        self.inputPropHighwayWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"inputPropHighwayWInter")
        self.inputPropHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 530, 151, 31))

        self.inputNormCitySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setObjectName(u"inputNormCitySummer")
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 590, 151, 31))

        self.inputNormHighwaySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"inputNormHighwaySummer")
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 630, 151, 31))

        self.inputNormCityWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setObjectName(u"inputNormCityWinter")
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 590, 151, 31))

        self.inputNormHighwayWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"inputNormHighwayWInter")
        self.inputNormHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 630, 151, 31))

        root.setCentralWidget(self.grid_w)
        self.retranslateUi(root)

        self.btnHelp.setDefault(False)
        self.btnGear.setDefault(False)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(root)

    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, root):
        root.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"BenzConfig", None))
        self.inputSummer.setInputMask("")
        self.inputSummer.setText("")
        self.inputSummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                                       u"\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435",
                                                                       None))
        self.outSummer.setText("")
        self.btnSummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
        #if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnSummer.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"Return", None))
        #endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
        #if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnWinter.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"Tab", None))
        #endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.outWinter.setText("")
        self.inputWinter.setText("")
        self.inputWinter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                                       u"\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435",
                                                                       None))
        self.label_s.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041b\u0435\u0442\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
        self.lable_w.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0417\u0438\u043c\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
        self.btnAbout.setText("")
        self.btnHelp.setText("")
        self.btnGear.setText("")
        self.labelPropSummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0446\u0438\u0438", None))
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.labelNormSummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                                u"\u041d\u043e\u0440\u043c\u044b \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0430",
                                                                None))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.labelPropWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0446\u0438\u0438", None))
        self.labelNormWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                                u"\u041d\u043e\u0440\u043c\u044b \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0430",
                                                                None))
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputPropHighwayWinter.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputNormHighwayWinter.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
    # retranslateUi


Как вариант. Тестировал на summer.
winter - вам для домашней работы.
main.py
import sys
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from PySide6.QtCore import QSettings
from design import Ui_root
sys.argv += ['-platform', 'windows:darkmode=1']
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from design import Ui_root


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_root):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # setting save
        self.btnSet.clicked.connect(self.saveProperty)
        self.btnSet.setShortcut(QApplication.translate("root", u"Ctrl+S", None))
        
        # property
        self.propCity = None
        self.propHighway = None
        self.normCity = None
        self.normHighway = None
        self.propCityWinter = None
        self.normCityWinter = None
        self.propHighwayWinter = None
        self.normHighwayWinter = None

        # function
        self.btnSummer.clicked.connect(self.funcSummer) 
        self.btnWinter.clicked.connect(self.funcWinter)

        # menubar
        self.btnAbout.clicked.connect(self.funcAbout)
        self.btnHelp.clicked.connect(self.funcHelp)
        self.btnGear.setCheckable(True)
        self.btnGear.clicked.connect(self.funcGear)

        # summer 
        self.applyPropCitySummer.clicked.connect(self.newPropCitySummer) 
        self.applyNormCitySummer.clicked.connect(self.newNormCitySummer) 
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.clicked.connect(self.newPropHighwaySummer) 
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.clicked.connect(self.newNormHighwaySummer) 

        #winter
        self.applyPropCityWinter.clicked.connect(self.newPropCityWinter)
        self.applyNormCityWinter.clicked.connect(self.newNormCityWinter)
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.clicked.connect(self.newPropHighwayWinter)
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.clicked.connect(self.newNormHighwayWinter)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
       
        self.load_settings()
        
    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings("q1577134_settings.ini", QSettings.IniFormat) 
        
        self.inputSummer.setText(settings.value('inputSummer', ""))
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setText(settings.value('inputPropCitySummer', ""))
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setText(settings.value('inputPropHighwaySummer', ""))
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setText(settings.value('inputNormCitySummer', ""))
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setText(settings.value('inputNormHighwaySummer', ""))
        
        if self.inputPropCitySummer.text():
            self.applyPropCitySummer.click() 
        if self.inputNormCitySummer.text():
            self.applyNormCitySummer.click() 
        if self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text(): 
            self.applyPropHighwaySummer.click() 
        if self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text(): 
            self.applyNormHighwaySummer.click() 
        
    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    def saveProperty(self):
        settings = QSettings("q1577134_settings.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)

        settings.setValue("inputSummer", self.inputSummer.text())
        settings.setValue("inputPropCitySummer", self.inputPropCitySummer.text())
        settings.setValue("inputPropHighwaySummer", self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text())
        settings.setValue("inputNormCitySummer", self.inputNormCitySummer.text())
        settings.setValue("inputNormHighwaySummer", self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text())

        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
            "Настройки", f"Новые данные сохранены.")
#        settings.sync()
    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    # summer
    def funcSummer(self):
        try:
            # Пропорции город лето
            if self.propCity:
                propCity = self.propCity
            else:
                propCity = 0.3

                # Нормы город лето
            if self.normCity:
                normCity = self.normCity
            else:
                normCity = 11.5

                # Пропорции трасса лето
            if self.propHighway:
                propHighway = self.propHighway
            else:
                propHighway = 0.7

                # Нормы трасса лето
            if self.normHighway:
                normHighway = self.normHighway
            else:
                normHighway = 8.5

            inSummer = float(self.inputSummer.text())
            roadCity = round(propCity * inSummer, 2)
            roadHighway = round(propHighway * inSummer, 2)
            resultCity = round(propCity * inSummer / 100 * normCity, 2)
            resultHighway = round(propHighway * inSummer / 100 * normHighway, 2)
            totalSummer = round((propCity * inSummer / 100 * normCity) + \
                (propHighway * inSummer / 100 * normHighway), 2)
            self.outSummer.setText(
                f' Ваш расход составил {totalSummer} литров\n\n'
                f' Детальная информация \n'
                f' Пробег по городу {roadCity} км \n'
                f' Расход по городу {resultCity} литров\n'
                f' Пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км \n'
                f' Расход по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                f' Нормы расхода\n'
                f' Город {normCity} на 100 км\n'
                f' Трасса {normHighway} на 100 км\n\n'
                f' Пропорции\n'
                f' Коэф. по городу {propCity}\n'
                f' Коэф. по трассе {propHighway}'
            )
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 
                f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные -->`inputSummer`.")

    def newPropCitySummer(self):
        try:
            self.propCity = float(self.inputPropCitySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()

        except Exception as e:
            self.propCity = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputPropCitySummer.text()}</b>")

    def newNormCitySummer(self):
        try:
            self.normCity = float(self.inputNormCitySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normCity = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputNormCitySummer.text()}</b>")

    def newPropHighwaySummer(self):
        try:
            self.propHighway = float(self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propHighway = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text()}</b>")

    def newNormHighwaySummer(self):
        try:
            self.normHighway = float(self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normHighway = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text()}</b>")

    # winter
    def funcWinter(self):
        try:
            if self.propCityWinter:         # Пропорции город зима
                propCityWinter = self.propCityWinter
            else:
                propCityWinter = 0.3

            if self.normCityWinter:         # Нормы город зима
                normCityWinter = self.normCityWinter
            else:
                normCityWinter = 13.8

            if self.propHighwayWinter:      # Пропорции трасса зима
                propHighwayWinter = self.propHighwayWinter
            else:
                propHighwayWinter = 0.7

            if self.normHighwayWinter:      # Нормы трасса зима
                normHighwayWinter = self.normHighwayWinter
            else:
                normHighwayWinter = 10.2

            inWinter = float(self.inputWinter.text())
            roadCity = round(propCityWinter * inWinter, 2)
            roadHighway = round(propHighwayWinter * inWinter, 2)
            resultCity = round(propCityWinter * inWinter / 100 * normCityWinter, 2)
            resultHighway = round(propHighwayWinter * inWinter / 100 * normHighwayWinter, 2)
            totalWinter = round((propCityWinter * inWinter / 100 * normCityWinter) + (
                    propHighwayWinter * inWinter / 100 * normHighwayWinter), 2)
            self.outWinter.setText(
                f' Ваш расход составил {totalWinter} литров\n\n'
                f' Детальная информация \n'
                f' Пробег по городу {roadCity} км \n'
                f' Расход по городу {resultCity} литров\n'
                f' Пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км \n'
                f' Расход по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                f' Нормы расхода\n'
                f' Город {normCityWinter} на 100 км\n'
                f' Трасса {normHighwayWinter} на 100 км\n\n'
                f' Пропорции\n'
                f' Коэф. по городу {propCityWinter}\n'
                f' Коэф. по трассе {propHighwayWinter}'
            )
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                                  f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newPropCityWinter(self):
        try:
            self.propCityWinter = float(self.inputPropCityWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propCityWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newNormCityWinter(self):
        try:
            self.normCityWinter = float(self.inputNormCityWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normCityWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newPropHighwayWinter(self):
        try:
            self.propHighwayWinter = float(self.inputPropHighwayWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propHighwayWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newNormHighwayWinter(self):
        try:
            self.normHighwayWinter = float(self.inputNormHighwayWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normHighwayWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    # bar
    def funcGear(self):
        if self.btnGear.isChecked():
            self.resize(560, 670)
        else:
            self.resize(560, 450)

    def funcAbout(self):
        strAbout = """
            BenzConfig ver. 0.7\n
            Copyright © Чекаев В.А.
            Ресурсы www.flaticon.com\n
            Лицензия
            GNU General Public License v3.0
            """

        msgAbout = QMessageBox()
        msgAbout.setWindowTitle("About")
# --------------------------------->  vvvvvvvvv <------------------ установите свое 
        msgAbout.setWindowIcon(QIcon('image.svg'))

        msgAbout.setText(strAbout)
# ---------------------------------->  vvvvvvvvvv <---------------- установите свое 
        msgAbout.setIconPixmap(QPixmap("lena3.png"))

        msgAbout.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgAbout.exec()
        
    def funcHelp(self):
        strAbout = """
        Пропорции перерасчета расхода
        город/трасса 30% на 70%\n
        HOTKEYS
        Рассчет Летнего пробега клавиша "Enter"
        Рассчет Зимнего пробега клавиша "Tab"
            """

        msgAbout = QMessageBox()
        msgAbout.setWindowTitle("Help")
# --------------------------------->  vvvvvv <------------------ установите свое         
        msgAbout.setWindowIcon(QIcon('im.svg'))

        msgAbout.setText(strAbout)
# --------------------------------->   vvvvvvvvvv <------------- установите свое 
        msgAbout.setIconPixmap(QPixmap("lena3.png"))

        msgAbout.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgAbout.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

design.py
без изменений




@ S.Nick спасибо, работает, с зимний сделал так же, только возникла небольшая проблема, теперь при перезапуске программы она запоминает новые параметры, но открывается сразу последним расчетом, это можно как-то пофиксить?

@VadimChekaev пожалуйста. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. Приведите ваш код и хорошо расскажите, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

@ S.Nick хорошо, спасибо
